# Nginx: right chmod permissions for sock file

Tags: django, nginx

Setting up a site using nginx and in the error logs it's denied permissions for the sock file.

```
22017/01/26 08:42:38 [crit] 2362#2362: *1 connect() to unix:///tmp/kb.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.232.12.165, server: kenyabuzz.nation.news, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/kb.sock:", host: "kenyabuzz.nation.news"
```

What would be the optimal chmod rights to set for the sock file?